# Can someone help me parse value of element from nested JSON response. I want to display value or "priceInCents" on html page here is my script

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

**Can someone help me parse the value of an element from nested JSON response. I want to display value or "priceInCents" on HTML page here is my script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo1"> 
<h1>Product price</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc1()">check price</button>
</div>
<script>
function loadDoc1() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = obj.results.price.priceInCents;
         }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=329264833&store=148", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't know what is `this.responseText`. OR do we?

Comment: We do here, OP posted the link.

Comment: this.responseText is JSON response that we are getting from url http://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=329264833&store=148

Answer (score 1):

`results` is an array, so you have to specify that you want the first element of the array.

```js
function loadDoc1() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = obj.results[0].price.priceInCents;
         }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://search.mobile.walmart.com/search?query=329264833&store=148", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1"> 
<h1>Product price</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc1()">check price</button>
</div>
```